# Integration vs Summation

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics, power-series

I am interested in how one might generally evaluate, or estimate

$$G(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)x^n-\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)x^tdt$$
 as $x\to1^-$, and for a continuous $f$, and such that the integral and the power series both converge in some suitable region.

One would expect that the limit (I am only really interested in what happens when $x$ approaches 1 or some other root of unity) would generally exist, but perhaps there are some cases where the difference blows up. Any ideas on how this function $G(x)$ behaves asymptotically would be very useful.

Comment: Usually, when I need to compare the sum with the integral I assume $f$ positive and then I divide the semi-line $[0,\infty] $ in intervals of length 1. If you do this, the sum starting from 1 is the sum of the rectangles' area with height $f(x)$ and width 1. A simple draw can tell you what happens if you start the sum from 1 or zero.

Comment: I would recommend trying to use the Euler-Maclaurin formula.

Comment: I had a look at that veritable monstrosity. I cannot say it looks enticing!

Comment: How about [Abel-Plana Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel-Plana_formula) ?.

Comment: Whoah! Now that's a formula baby. I had never even heard of that before.